# how to create a shopping cart in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

i'm trying to create a shopping cart with reactjs this is my code so far...

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import {Link} from "react-router-dom"
class Food extends Component{
    constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.state = {
    total: 0,
      };
      this.sum = this.sum.bind(this);
    }

    sum(){

    }
   render(){
       if(this.props.product !== undefined){

       var items = this.props.product.map((index) => {
        let grid = 12/this.props.product.length;
        let menu_item_href = '/menu-item';

           return (

<Grid item xs={grid} key={index.ProductID}>
<Paper className="food-item">
<div>
    <h3>{index.Name}</h3>
    <p>Excerpt: {index.Excerpt}</p>
    <p>price: {index.Price}</p>
    <div onClick={this.sum}>sum</div>
   <Link to={menu_item_href}><p>more...</p></Link>
    </div>
</Paper> 
</Grid> 

           )
       })

    }
      return(

         <div>
<h2>{this.props.cat}</h2>
<Grid container spacing={24}>
{items}
</Grid>
{this.state.total}
         </div>

       );
   }
}
export default Food;
```

as you see i map trough an array and create shop items, i want create a shop cart that works like this:
when a user click on "add item" button the name and the number of item add to bill and the price sum with total and total update. i now its complicated if you now any tutorial that might help me to create an shopping cart please let me now and i would be appreciate.thank youreact

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add the code with what you have tried so the community can have a look and help you with a specific problem. Also, please have a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal-complete-verifiable-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please don't ask the community to do everything for you as it will make it harder for you to get help. Rather, try coding and if you get stuck and have some error you can post them here and rest assured that you will get help!